# How to import a library in TypeScript when its type definitions do not declare a module?

Tags: typescript, peerjs

PeerJS has type definitions, but they are not exported as a module. They are declarations of types under some namespace.

I am getting: `[ts] File 'c:/Users/Vincas/Desktop/language-exchange/node_modules/@types/peerjs/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

When trying to import it: `import Peer from 'peerjs'`
This tries to import from type definitions, rather than the module itself, how do I import from a module here?

The file from DefinitelyTyped is here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/peerjs/index.d.ts

I've worked around for the time being like this:

```
const PeerJS: typeof Peer = require('peerjs')
const peerjs = new PeerJS({ key: '**********' })
```

But this is so much inferior to: `import * as Peer from 'peerjs` or something similar... Is there no way to avoid defining global functions and global namespaces? That just looks like a terrible practice to me.

Comment: Can you include a sample of that .d.ts file?

Comment: I was able to import it via require('peerjs'), but that is not very consistent with TS import syntax...

Comment: Wondering... Do the type declarations work if you do `import PeerJs = require('peerjs')`?

Comment: No they don't, it has to be a constant definition, but then I don't get the type definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registered type declarations in the package `@types/peerjs` are specified as globals. That is, they state the presence of the namespace `PeerJs` and the variable `Peer` as global declarations (also called "ambient").

```
declare var Peer: {
   // ...
}
```

This suggests that they were meant to be used with the distributable library file ["dist/peer.js"](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/blob/master/dist/peer.js) rather than with the module. If one were to include this file directly into the page, the compiler should be able to know that these globals are available.

But indeed, you want to use the module instead. Unfortunately, the same declarations are not compatible, and must be re-written for conformance. An old issue on the repository was left open ([#176](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/176)), and you seem to have created [#386](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/386) not long ago. Your intuition here appears to be right: ideally, someone will have to adapt these 
declarations. In this case, since the object exported from the library is a class, we should follow the [class module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html) pattern. Instead of `declare var Peer`, we can have something like this:

```
export = Peer;
declare class Peer {
    constructor(id: string, options?: Peer.PeerJSOption);
    constructor(options: Peer.PeerJSOption);
    // remaining methods here ...
};

declare namespace Peer {
    export interface PeerJSOption {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The additional interface types are put inside a namespace with the same name, so that everything is exported properly.

I took the task by my own hands: a new file ["index.d.ts"](https://github.com/Enet4/peerjs/blob/typescript-types/index.d.ts) was added to the repository, along with a few extra package.json fields, in [this branch](https://github.com/Enet4/peerjs/tree/typescript-types). This makes declarations work just by installing the main dependency, no other packages are needed (in particular, you should not add "@types/peerjs").

You can even try it yourself:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-peerjs-ts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "peerjs": "git+https://github.com/Enet4/peerjs.git#typescript-types"
  }
}
```

index.ts:

```
import Peer = require('peerjs');

let peer = new Peer("id");
let peer2 = new Peer("id", {});

type DataConn = Peer.DataConnection;
```

You might only see a bunch of TypeScript errors from the `webrtc` typings, which apparently contain definitions already available in the latest TypeScript compilers. Still, the compilation process will work successfully and yield good JavaScript code:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var Peer = require("peerjs");
var peer = new Peer("id");
var peer2 = new Peer("id", {});
```

Comment: That change would be enough to provide definition for exported function's type, but then I can't access the types under PeerJs namespace, as this now doesn't get exported nor defined on the global scope.

Comment: How do I export it? If I write `export = Peer`, then I cannot export anything else it seems. If I export them separately: `export { Peer, PeerJs }`, then it doesn't match what is in the module itself, and Peer will be undefined. If I somehow managed to export them separately, I would have to import them separately as well, something like:
`import { PeerJs } from 'peerjs; import * as Peer from 'peerjs'`, or otherwise use the namespace like: `Peer.PeerJs.Peer` which doesn't look good at all.

Comment: I updated the answer again. The solution to that is to declare the namespace under the same name.

Comment: Won't this cause ambiguity? I am trying to use another library, that exports the class+namespace like this, and I can't get it to work, because whenever I try to use it as a class, it thinks it's a namespace... Here's the issue regarding that: https://github.com/gor181/react-notification-system-redux/issues/37

Comment: There is no ambiguity. This pattern is an exact recommendation from the official TypeScript documentation, and many other type declarations for non-TS libraries follow these patterns. As for that other case, you should use the TypeScript-specific syntax `import x = require('foo')`, as explained in the [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) section.

Comment: OK, thanks, I didn't see that in the docs, while skimming through them.

Comment: I don't know if I'm stupid or what, but whenever there is an exporter namespace (`declare namespace Something`) and a class (`declare class Something`) of the same name, and after importing (`import Something  = require('something')`) I can't use it as a class, it always says that it's not assignable to type, or has no call or construct, basically meaning that it tries to use Namespace rather than Class...

Comment: Hopefully this should be one of the final answer updates. Please try the example above. :)

Comment: They look really good, at least they are correctly detected as a module, and a class. I find it hard to make this work though: `import Peer = require('peerjs')` `const peer = new Peer("id")` `this.peer.on('call',handleCall);`

It highlights `.on` as non-existant on Peer.

Comment: Hah, that was my bad, they were incomplete. Please force-pull from the repository again.

Comment: I also created [PR #387](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/pull/387), we'll see whether it's ok to have it there. If not, we'll have to request a breaking change to `@types/peerjs`.

Comment: That's perfect, I've imported them and nothing shows up as an error now. I like it when the libs have their own types, not in @types, so hopefully it gets accepted :)